# How to reset a form field conditionally when another one changes using vue.js

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, methods

I have two form fields `retrieval-method` and `source-url`, where the later depends on the value of the former. Specifically the text box `source-url` should be disabled for particular values of `retrieval-method`. I can achieve this fairly simply as follows:

**`https://jsfiddle.net/o5mzhg3y/`**

```html
<div id="app">
  <select name="retrieval-method" v-model="retrieval_method">
    <option value="">Choose a method</option>
    <option value="1">Upload</option>
    <option value="2">Download (Periodic)</option>
    <option value="3">Download (API Triggered)</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="source-url" :disabled="!(retrieval_method>1)">
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        retrieval_method: false,
        source_url: ''
      }
    })
</script>
```

However I would like to be able to also reset the fields value to an empty string when the retrieval method changes to something that causes the input to be disabled. But I can't wrap my mind around how to do this. Perhaps I need to implement a method?

Ideally the value would not be forgotten so that if the user changes `retrieval-method` back to a value that requires a source url the value is reinserted into the text input.

Comment: I have updated your requirement in the https://jsfiddle.net/v9wymLcr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to do a few things. You can add a watcher to your `retrieval_method` property. Listen for changes when value changed you save your `source_url` into a backup field when disable condition is true. And in reverse you read back from your backup filed to your `source_url`. You should also change your input binding to a `v-model` binding in order to reflect changes.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    retrieval_method: false,
    source_url: '',
    backupUrl: ''

  },
  computed: {
    disableUrl: function() {
      return this.retrieval_method <= 1;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    // whenever question changes, this function will run
    retrieval_method: function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue <= 1) {
        this.backupUrl = this.source_url;
        this.source_url = '';
      } else if (this.backupUrl) {     
        this.source_url = this.backupUrl;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select name="retrieval-method" v-model="retrieval_method">
    <option value="">Choose a method</option>
    <option value="1">Upload</option>
    <option value="2">Download (Periodic)</option>
    <option value="3">Dowload (API Triggered)</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" v-model="source_url" :disabled="disableUrl" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up figuring it out by binding a method to the change event

**`https://jsfiddle.net/o5mzhg3y/7/`**

```html
<div id="app">
  <select name="retrieval-method" v-model="retrieval_method" v-on:change="retrieval_method_changed">
    <option value="">Choose a method</option>
    <option value="1">Upload</option>
    <option value="2">Download (Periodic)</option>
    <option value="3">Dowload (API Triggered)</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="source-url" :disabled="source_disabled" v-model="source_url">
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        retrieval_method: '',
        source_disabled: true,
        source_url: '',
        old_source_url: '',
    },
    methods: {
        retrieval_method_changed: function (event) {
            const old_source_disabled = this.source_disabled
            this.source_disabled = !(this.retrieval_method>1)
            if( old_source_disabled != this.source_disabled) {
                if(this.source_disabled) {
                    this.old_source_url = this.source_url
                    this.source_url = ''
                } else {
                    this.source_url = this.old_source_url
                    this.old_source_url = ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

I'm going to leave the question open though, in case someone comes up with a cleaner way to do what I wanted